# Como analisar erro javascript em resposta do Firefox DEV

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Usando o firefox dev, existe o console (ctrl+shift+k), e dentro desse console existem as respostas, as respostas de erros PHP são simples, ou quando uma variável é passada vazia, mas porém, quando é um erro de sintaxe em javascript, a mensagem é um pouco diferente e agrupa várias coisas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual é a maneira mais correta de se interpretar essa resposta do console ? 
Ou, onde existe um manual acerca disso ?

PS: eu fiz este erro propositalmente, não quero a solução pra este erro, quero saber como entender quando houver esse tipo de resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os erros geralmente são tratados no TypeError, nesse caso diz que você chamou um objeto chamado "enabled" que não existe. 
Seria interessante colocar o código js aqui para dar uma analisada!

Caso clicar sobre o "link" que está apresentando o erro o firefox mostra onde está o erro.